# Передача данных с формы в jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть вот такой код формы. Он по сути отправляет директорию, в которой расположено изображение и само название изображения.

```
<form id="ajax_form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="image_dir" value="'.$directory.'/'.$file.'">
    <button type="submit" class="button btn">Просмотр</button>
</form>
```

Понятно, что есть какой-то такой код, но как в этом коде поймать значение input с именем image_dir не совсем понимаю, т.к. в js совсем не силен

```
$("#ajax_form").submit(
    function(){


    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var image_dir  = $("input[name=image_dir]").val();
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло!